# How can I ensure that the autoGeneratedKeyType gets set correctly in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, breeze

We have been having problems related to Breeze and Chrome which I tracked down to the autoGeneratedKeyType not being set correctly for EntityTypes in Chrome.

This is an extract from the metadata that is being returned during calls to fetchMetadata(). Note the `annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern` property has a value of `Identity`.

```
  {
    "name": "FileNote",
    "customannotation:ClrType": "FileNotes.FileNote, FileNotes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "key": { "propertyRef": { "name": "ID" } },
    "property": [
      {
        "name": "ID",
        "type": "Edm.Int32",
        "nullable": "false",
        "annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern": "Identity"
      },
```

Right after the fetchMetadata promise completes in browsers other than Chrome, the autoGeneratedKeyType for this type has a value of `Identity`.

```
metadataStore.getEntityType("FileNote").autoGeneratedKeyType.name
```

When I repeat this in Chrome, I am seeing a value of `None`.

How can I ensure that the value is also correct in Chrome?

**Chrome Version**: 51.0.2704.84

**Update:** We noticed that the debugger seems to affect this behaviour. When we put a breakpoint on the first line of parseCsdlSimpleProperty with a condition of false in the Chrome Developer Tools, the autogeneratedKeyType property is correctly set to Identity.

[image: Conditional Breakpoint]

Note that putting a breakpoint with the same condition on the call to parseCsdlSimpleProperty from parseCsdlDataProperty does not have the same effect (autogeneratedKeyType is set to None).